# How to lower the ping on WIFI for better gameplay?

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, ping, gaming

I suffer from very high ping in the game Fortnite that ranges from 80 to 100. Basically, I do have an ethernet cable, but It is inconvenient for me to connect it to my gaming laptop in my private room.

There is so much lag in the game that makes the experience awful. I want to know what steps can I follow to lower the ping for better experience.

What tweaks and adjustments do I have to make to lower the ping on WIFI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your answer, the router is outside the room where the computer
is situated, and there is a very big difference when the door is closed
or open.
When the door is closed, ping times are multiplied by an order of magnitude.

My conclusions are:

- The walls and door block the WiFi signal
- If the walls and door do not incorporate metallic elements, then the router
  is extremely weak, or the WiFi network adapter in your computer is very weak.

As solution I can only offer:

- Connect to the router using an Ethernet cable.
  There are solutions for closing the door on the cable.
  If the cable doesn't pass below the door, a small hole
  might need to be drilled in the door frame.
  Ethernet cables can go to several dozens of meters without any problem.
- Experiment with using 5/2.4 Ghz signals. 5 Ghz is faster, but 2.4 Ghz is
  better at bypassing walls.
  Please note that within the 2.4 GHz band, only three channels have non-overlapping frequency space: channels one, six and eleven.
- Factory reset the router, to see if this is caused by some bad setting.
  Look also for a firmware update, as perhaps a better version is available.
- Try a USB external WiFi network adapter of good quality.
- If all fails, get a stronger router that can punch through wall and door.
  (A new external WiFi network adapter might still be required.)

Answer (score 3):

Pick the least overbooked WiFi channel with the strongest signal.

Depending on whether your operating system and WiFi driver let you:

1. Disable WiFi power management
2. Turn up tx power as far as the driver will let you, usually 20mW

That's about the limit of what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

If by wifi all websites are affected by high ping and by wired It is okay then it is **Wifi adapter or Router issue**.Since you have stated about fortnite game issue I am also stating below fixes because they also are reasons to cause fortnite lag

1.First check distance between wifi router and connected device and signal
If low signal and high distance surely internet will be slow and high ping will occur

2.Close network consuming applications by task manager
ReLaunch Fortnite to see if this issue solves

3.Check and Update your network driver
Old Network drivers also cause issue in slowing internet and heavy lag
Also keep windows updated regularly for patches fixes

4.Disable the proxy server or VPN if you use to connect Fortnite their use cause high ping
Proxy VPNs encrypt traffic causing lag and slow

5.Change your matchmaking region to closest area
If nothing works, you may need to check if it is a server issue.

Comment: In the comments of the question, the OP said that their ping between their PC and their own router was ranging from 1ms to 80+ms. It is not an issue with the game or the game servers, and it's unlikely that it's bandwidth-related as the local router pings are so erratic. I agree that a network driver could also be the culprit, but I suspect the issue lies in the router or in interference between the PC and the router.

Comment: He stated also about fortnite also so I have given all possible solutions

Comment: Yes, but if they are having erratic pings like that to local, non-internet addresses, then does it not make sense that whatever is causing that issue is also causing the Fortnite issue?

Comment: I updated my graphics driver but the ping didn't improve. As for matchmaking, it is set to auto. The lowest ping is chosen automatically.

Comment: Update the network driver for network issues

Comment: Yeah I will try.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). By not quoting the  referenced content you are committing plagiarism.

Answer (score -3):

If the Ping to your router if over 10ms (on average), there is something off with the router or your machine.
Any of the processor is peaking while handling network packages So the pings response gets delayed since they have a lower priority.
Any Antivirus or Endpoint protection in your PC?

Comment: Windows defender is disabled and I have no other antivirus.